# Reading non static values in MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

How do I read non-static values in view using Razor view

```
// MODEL
public int Number1 { get; set; }
public int Number2 { get; set; }

// VIEW
@using BasicCalculator.Events.Models;

@{   
 Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Html.TextBox("Number1",?????
```

I have to read the properties(Number1 and Number2) in the view...

Comment: When I'm using using BasicCalculator.Events.Models.Calculator...then it shows me html with all intellisense but I can not read non-static members from the model.....but when I'm using model BasicCalculator.Events.Models.Calculator then it can not identify html and there is no intellisense...........any idea??

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `TextBoxFor` which binds to your model when you pass in an expression:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Number1)
```

But to do this you will need to change your `using` statement to `model`:

```
@model BasicCalculator.Events.Models.YourModelName
```

Comment: As I tried this, it can not identify Html.....do I have to do anything different for a view present inside Shared View Folder

Answer (score 1):

Change your `@using` to a `@model`:

```
@model BasicCalculator.Events.Models.YourModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Number1)
```

Comment: When I do so, its showing @HTML does not exists in the current context...then I imported System.Web.Mvc namespace...but now it can not identify  .TextBox.....

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your commentary of @CodeCaster's answer, your view cannot find Namespaces for @HTML and when you import System.Web.Mvc namespace he can't identify .TextBox.

I suggest that you go your Web.config file inside your View folder.
Search for the tag  inside .
Be sure all Namespaces you need in your View are in there.

Yuou should have the somethink like the following :

```
<namespaces>
   <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
   <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
   <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
   <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
   <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
</namespaces>
```

Hope this might help.

Comment: All mentioned above are there in the config

Comment: If you have not solved your problem yet. Have you others namespaces included in your Web.config ?